# How can I get p value for Cronbach alpha?

Tags: validation, stata, reliability, significance

We assessed internal consistence reliability of a questionnaire (with seven item). The Cronbach alpha value was 0.79. However, I can't get its p value. What Stata commands shall I use?

I tried it with bootstrap but the output is only confidence interval.

Comment: What hypothesis are you testing?

Comment: Ho: chronbatch alpha is <0.7

Comment: As edited, the spelling is Cronbach. If that's your hypothesis, a confidence interval is indeed more usefu.

Comment: Thak you very much